# Multiple solutions to link a-text or other components entities in aframe still have error

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

This has been an issue with me on place links in aframe components.  So far, nothing has worked.  These are the three solutions I try to do:

1. Use **aframe-href-component** where I can just place an *href="www.sample.com"* in any entity.  Great, the problem is when I go to this cdn to get the [aframe-href-component.min.js](https://rawgit.com/gasolin/aframe-href-component/master/dist/aframe-href-component.min.js), I got a 404 error. Maybe the author pulled it off. So this is a dead end.
2. Reported aframe issue #403, last closed in 2016, when the author Kevin Ngo which takes me to git pull #1575, where there is a new [link.js component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/1575) added.  This means I can just use *link* attribute in my component.  For example:

   `<a-text link="https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1998/01/08/labor-leader-jack-t-conway-dies" id="chrysler-caption" position="-5.40 6.70 -0.30" rotation="0 0 0" scale="1 1 1" value="JACK T. CONWAY"></a-text>`
3. Somebody mentioned in another Stack Overflow post to just add my own component, so here, I created this one:

   ```
   AFRAME.registerComponent('link-url', {
             schema: {default: ''},

             init: function () {
               var url = this.data;
               this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
                 window.location.href = url;
               });
             }
           });
   ```

So I try to implement this in my aframe [picture gallery here](https://early-periodical.glitch.me/).  I tried all the two options, but for some reason, by text file on the top-left most image cannot be linked to an outside article (regular post in a news site, not AFRAME site).

I suspect something is going on with my custom registered AFRAME component, but it will be great to know how to link to an on-click.

Answer (score 1):

2) You need to add `href: link` to the `link` component:

```
<a-text link="href:https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/local/1998/01/08/labor-leader-jack-t-conway-dies"></a-text>
```

3) According to the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#defining-properties-with-the-schema), the schema works like this: declare a variable, and access it in the `data` object:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  schema: {
    {myvalue: {default: ""}
  },
  init: function() {
    var myvalue = this.data.myvalue
  }
})

<a-box foo="myvalue: 10">
```

so, you can't just try to access some imaginary variable in `data`, you need to "declare" it in the schema, and then you can access the value.

Check out both 2) and 3)  [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/neat-broker?path=index.html:17:0) (glitch), or [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pa9m3upx/1/) (fiddle, but won't allow redirecting)

Comment: There are no properties in the `data` object by default ever. p.s., check https://github.com/supermedium/gunters-of-oasis for an implementation of links, hundreds of interconnected / generated worlds using portals.

Comment: @ngokevin thanks for claryfing, i was sure, that some properties are created there in the Component constructor :P 
Thanks for the tip, i like how the "back" button is made using local storage [here](https://github.com/supermedium/gunters-of-oasis/blob/master/src/components/oasis-portal.js) :)